# How to get image from url in react

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-storage

I am trying to upload an image saved as a URL. The 'img' field holds the URL for the image in firebase storage. How can I use this URL to upload an image in react?

[image: firestore set up]

Comment: I'm confused by what you mean when you say, _"to upload an image in React."_ Can you clarify your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The URL in your screenshot starts with `gs://` which means that it is a file stored in Cloud Storage.

Such URLs are not recognized by most browsers and libraries, but you can use the Firebase SDK for Cloud Storage to exchange it for a so-called download URL. This is a regular HTTP URL, that browser and libraries are expecting.

To learn how to get a download URL from your `gs://` URL, have a look at the Firebase documentation on [creating a reference to a file](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/download-files#download_data_via_url) and [downloading a file via a URL](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/download-files#download_data_via_url).